# yii2fullcalendar not rendering after port

Tags: yii2, fullcalendar

I recently moved a production Yii2 app to a new virtual machine.  The old VPS was a CentOS on GoDaddy and the new one is an Ubuntu 22.04 VM running on an internal ESXi host. The Yii version on the VPS is 2.0.23 and on the VM it's 2.0.47.

The only problem so far is with the FullCalendar extension: philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar.  Both VMs use the same version 3.9.0, but the new VM does not render the calendar widget properly.

The old (correct) rendering:
[image]

The new (broken) rendering:
[image]

It's a pretty straightforward setup.  The view code:

```
<?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget([
        'events' => $events,
        'id' => 'home-calendar',
        'clientOptions' => [
            'eventClick' => new JsExpression($js_event_click),
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

The controller action:

```
$homeEvents = HomeEvent::find()->all();
$events = [];
foreach ($homeEvents as $homeEvent) {
    $event = new Event([
        'id' => $homeEvent->id,
        'title' => $homeEvent->title,
        'allDay' => ($homeEvent->all_day == "T"),
        'start' => $homeEvent->start_dt,
        'end' => $homeEvent->end_dt,
        'editable' => true,
        'className' => ($homeEvent->all_day == 'T') ? 'fc-event-allday' : null,
    ]);
    $events[] = $event;
}
...
return $this->render('homepage', [
    'events' => $events,
...
]);
```

There are 2 other hosts where this widget is running as expected, on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM and my MacOS Ventura test computer. PHP version is 5.6 on all 4 hosts.

Any ideas?

Comment: what are the bootstrap versions used , are you getting any errors in console for js, or missing asset files.  Did you run the composer separately on both the hosts, or copied the vendor folder over to the newer host from the old one ?

Comment: At a guess, maybe some CSS files aren't downloading properly. This code runs in the browser, so the VM wouldn't directly affect it, unless there's some problem with accessing files that the web page requires. Open your browser's developer tools, go to the Network area, and load the calendar page into the browser. Then see if any of the files it requires don't get downloaded with a 200 OK response. That's likely to be a clue to your issue.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yii2 bootstrap is 2.0.11 in the new, 2.0.10 in the old.  No console errors.  No missing asset file that I can tell.  Yes, I did run composer separately on each host, but specified yii2-fullcalendar 3.9.0 in the composer.json so they should match.

Comment: @ADyson Everything shows 200 OK, including the stylesheets.  Just to make sure, I cleared out the web/assets directory and browser cache.  Same results.

Comment: Ok. And nothing else different, like jquery version, or any other additional CSS in the page, anything like that?

Comment: @ADyson bower-asset/jquery is 3.6.3 in new and 3.4.1 in the old.  bower-asset/moment is 2.24.0 in the old and 2.29.4 in the new.  Everything else looks the same.  The app source code is pulled from Git, so I know that's the same, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I narrowed it down to the allDay boolean property in the Event model.  The documentation says that this property "affects whether an event's time is shown."

If I don't include the property at all, the calendar renders correctly, except that the "all day" events all start with time: 12a (midnight), like this:

[image]

If I set the allDay property to true for these events, the time goes away, but the events render incorrectly, as in my OP above.

(I did view every YouTube tutorial I could find on FullCalendar/PHP integration, but none use the allDay property in their examples.)

Anyway, coded a CSS workaround in the view that displays the calendar.  I know that this code would be better suited in assets but I consider it a temporary fix for now.

```
<?php
  
$style = <<< CSS

.fc-event-allday .fc-content .fc-time {
    font-size: 0;
}

CSS;

$this->registerCss($style);
```

It appears that FullCalendar adds the class="fc-event-allday" tag when it sees midnight 00:00:00 in the start time portion, even if the AllDay property is omitted (assumed false).

Not elegant, but it works.

PS.  I don't know if philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar has been abandoned, but he has not replied to the issues page in GitHub in several years.  The latest "stable" release is 4.0.2, but most commenters agree that 3.9.0 is the most current working version.

Comment: As you're using a very old version of fullcalendar, it's quite likely this issue is fixed in later versions (I can't test it right now)

Comment: @ADyson Thanks. But like I mentioned, the Yii2 extension this program uses only works with FullCalendar 3.9.0.  One option I considered is skipping the extension altogether and installing a more current version of FullCalendar and coding to its API, but that would be an expensive change for my client.